# Adding item to OpenStreetMap dont arrives on Leaflet

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap, show

I made some changes today in my city's map. I added some locations and buildings. The changes is up and running on OpenStreetMap website, and even in some mobile apps on iPhone that uses OSM.

But the changes didn't arrived on any Leaflet example I tried. You can enter any Leaflet example at the location below and see by yourself.

One of the buildings I added is at exactly -7.958252, -36.205203.

[Building present on OpenStreetMap, but not on Leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmKjd.png)

Comment: Have a bit of patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes you made are directly applied to the OSM database. However each tile server has a different update schedule. The tile server for the standard layer on https://openstreetmap.org/ is usually pretty fast whereas other tile servers can take longer to update. According to your screenshot you use tiles provided by MapBox. The MapBox tile server is known to have a pretty long update delay.

You could try to switch to a different sever by specifying a different `tileLayer` in Leaflet. See https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ for a list of possible providers. Please make sure to respect their usage policy. Each tile server has its own policy.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand it. I just have to wait.